# Is it possible to change a user accounts role (with Cancan) automatically after a certain time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, cancan

In the app I'm making a user can own an account, and each account can be either free or premium (using roles and the Cancan gem).

I want to be able to upgrade free accounts to a premium role and select a duration such as 2 months, then after the 2 months are up have the account revert back to the free role automatically.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to solve this with a background job system like Resque or Delayed Job.

You can create a nightly job that reviews all of your free accounts and checks for the upgrade timestamp and reverts the role when their free trial expires.

Here's an example below of what that Account.revoke_expired_premium_roles() helper would look like, that you would call in a nightly background job or cron task:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  # assumes Timestamp field trial_expires_at set to 2.months.from_now by default on trial start
  named_scope :trial_expired, lambda {{ :conditions => ['trial_expires_at <= ?', Time.now] }}

  def self.revoke_expired_premium_roles
    trial_expired.find_each {|account| account.revoke_premium_role}
  end

  def revoke_premium_role
    # Remove can-can authorization here
  end
end
```